# Having trouble starting tomcat with a different JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I want to start my tomcat with a different java version than the "standard one". On my server java 6 is installed (java -version returns: `java version "1.6.0_34"`)
I also downloaded a java 7 jdk and put it to `/opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55/` and wanted my tomcat to run with java 7. So I added `export JAVA_HOME=/opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55` to my script `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`.

When I try to start my tomcat via `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start` I get `/opt/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java: not found`

But when I type `ll /opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55/bin` I get `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root java*` So the path should be correct!?

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Any hints appreciated. :-)

EDIT:
I probably just downloaded the wrong jdk (32 bit instead of 64)

Comment: what is the extension of your java inside bin?

Comment: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, BuildID[sha1]=0x6849323f527575e206a1b6449617e809158e82be, not stripped

Comment: What are the values of CATALINA_BASE,CATALINA_HOME ?

Comment: in catalina.sh I have
`export CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat7/workers/worker1` and
`export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat7`

Comment: Puzzling. When you execute '/opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java -version' without quotes you get a proper response?

Comment: hmm... `-bash: /opt/oracle/7/jdk1.7.0_55/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

You probably downloaded the wrong JDK. From your comments, it seems to be a 32bit JDK. If you have a 64bit Linux, then you can't load the executables.

`uname -m` tells you the architecture of your system. It should be `i686` or `i586` but probably is `x86_64`.

Comment: yeah I figured that out by myself and already edited my post, thank you though :)